# Отсутствие перевода в наименовании привилегий

Tags: дефект, локализация, привилегии

Перевод отключился недавно насколько я знаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может что-то отлетело неожиданно?)

P.S. я чекнул вроде таких вопросов не была здесь до меня, либо что-то пропустил :)

Comment: тоже самое для привилегии `Edit questions and answers`

Comment: У всех привилегий слетел перевод =\

Comment: лишь бы привилегии не слетели...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложил перевод для "Protect questions": https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14754

> Отмечать вопросы как защищённые

а также многих других непереведенных названий привилегий (какие удалось найти).