# Не переведено сообщение о новой привелегии

Tags: дефект, локализация, привилегии

Отсутствует локализация сообщения о получении новой привелегии.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Раньше я этого сообщения не замечал, кстати. Давно оно есть на RuSO?

Comment: [Они недавно что-то там поменяли](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10457/15479). Вероятно, тогда и появилось)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У этой строки теперь есть перевод: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13823

> Вы заработали новую привилегию!

Посмотрел по базе, перевод добавил [Adam Lear](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176103/adam-lear) 2020-05-29.

Кто будет получать новые привилегии, подтвердите, что перевод подхватился.